# How do I add a background for each image in a Gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, background, imageview

I have created Gridview. I want to set background image *(like glow in backside)* for the selected image in Gridview. How can I do it?

Comment: Post your code here with `GridView`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
myGridView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
     arg1.setBackgroundDrawable(d); //or arg1.setBackgroundResource(resid);
   }
});
```

Comment: How to disable that setBackgroundDrawable after focus/animation moving to another item from the currently focused item in a GridView..